# "pdflatex: Not writing to" error when using python

Tags: pdftex, python, database

I use python3 (with code not from me) to insert data from a database (bsddb3) into a LaTeX document and I receive the following error messages:

```
pdflatex: Not writing to .aux (openout_any = p).
! I can't write on file `.aux'.
```

The same happens with the `.out`, `.toc`, and `.lof` files. I understand the meaning of the message and that it is a precaution but I do not know why it would appear now while using the code. It never did by using pdflatex via CLI in other projects.

Shall I set an output directory when calling pdflatex via `-output-directory=DIR` or what would help here (without opening a security hole!)?

**Edit**

Second part of the error message:

```
\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux 
                                                  \immediate \write \@mainau...
l.22         \begin{document}
```

Line 22 does not help me to find the mistake in the python code at this point because the latex input is written into the python code.

Comment: is your command line something like `pdflatex ../foo/file.tex` if so it will fail to write `../foo/file.aux` so you need `cd ../foo; pdflatex file.tex`

Comment: Oh no, I misread, it literally means `.aux` that is you have managed to call latex with an empty filename what commandline did you use??

Comment: Ah, my error message I posted was not complete. See edit.

Comment: yes but that seems to imply that `\jobname` is empty, which is quite hard to acheive (tex uses the name `texput` if it is reading from stdin and doesn't have a real filename)

Comment: I fixed my problem. The name of the output file was empty and accepted like this by the python program.

Comment: interesting, could you self-answer, just to round things off, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my - admittedly - specific question: The name of the output file was empty and accepted like this by the python program.

Comment: you probably just saved me 3 hours

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro you are welcome. ;) I am glad it is helpful to someone!